# Explain why numpy should not be imported from source directory

Tags: python, import, numpy, matplotlib, directory

### Disclaimer of research:

I have examined the following other StackOverflow questions:

- [How to import numpy in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906575/how-to-import-numpy-in-python-shell/11906601#11906601)
- [How can I use numpy without installing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976503/how-can-i-use-numpy-without-installing-it)
- [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder)

Perhaps to some, those may answer my question, but according to my knowledge, I still do not understand the situation.

I am trying to import numpy so that matplotlib will work, but upon execution of the `__init__.py` file in the numpy folder, the following error message is displayed:

```
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
    its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
    your python intepreter from there.
```

Explain what it means to import something from its source directory as opposed to some other way of importing it. Does it mean that it should not be source code when it is imported? Or does it mean that it literally is just the wrong directory/folder that I am importing. I know that one other StackOverflow answer is:

> The message is fairly self-explanatory; your working directory should not be the numpy source directory when you invoke Python; numpy should be installed and your working directory should be anything but the directory where it lives.

However, I don't understand this. Aren't you supposed to import things that you want to work with? I'm assuming that the import command combines the source directory into your current working directory in this statement.

I also read the other answers such as:

- Using `distutils` to install local directories
- Using `virtualenv` to create a virtual system directory
- Using Enthought's EPD to have numpy pre-installed in what I believe to be the system directory,
  and
- Using a command like `$ dpkg -i --force-not-root --root=$HOME mypackagename.deb` to create what I believe is some kind of sub-system directory that is treated like a system directory.

So, correct me if I'm wrong, but does numpy somehow strongly require to be somehow installed in the main system directory?

### Machine status:

I am using Windows machines without administrative privlidges.
They have Python 3.3 Shell as well as matplotlib installed.
When running command prompt, `python` and `python3` are not recognized. I have to run the Python shell from the applications menu.
I can successfull begin importing matplotlib from even my own directory, different from theirs, but it stops upon reaching `__init__.py` of the numpy module, if it exists and reports the error stated above.

### Update:

Luckily, my administrators were able to directly install numpy correctly in the `site-packages` folder. Thank you for answering my question though. I understand the situation a lot more because of you.

Comment: I have numpy in the site-packages folder. Still does not work from eclipseEclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

Answer (score 14, accepted):

numpy includes extension modules written in C. You will need to build these extension modules before the numpy package is complete. The most robust way to do this is to build it and install it to `site-packages` like normal. You can also install it to another directory using the [standard distutils options for this](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation). However, once you have installed it, you should change your directory out of the source tree. Python starts looking for packages in your current directory, so the presence of the incomplete numpy package (without the necessary built C extension modules) will be picked up first and lead to the error that message that you quote. This happens a lot, so we give a long message explaining what to do.

Comment: Is the building of the extension modules of numpy necessary so that numpy can work with the os? Do all modules have extensions or only the "more advanced" ones?Does `pip` do the building when you invoke `pip install numpy`? Is there a beginner tutorial where I can build these C extensions?

Comment: 1. No, most of `numpy` is an extension module for speed.
2. The core of `numpy` is an extension module. You must build the extension modules.
3. If it can't find a prebuilt binary wheel, yes.
4. This is not the kind of thing that usually gets tutorial-style docs. Beginners should use the binaries on PyPI.
https://scipy.org/install.html
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/building.html

Comment: What does this mean: 'However, once you have installed it, you should change your directory out of the source tree.'
I have been struggling with this a lot and somehow it feels that changing my directory out of the source tree is key, but its cryptic. what is 'my directory' and what is source tree

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this error on raspberry pi. To fix it, I had to install a dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
```

Comment: This worked for me. It seems, everytime you upgrade numpy externally, you need to reinstall these dependencies to the new upgraded version. Especially for raspberry pi