# Using moviepy, scipy and numpy in amazon lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda

I'd like to generate video using `AWS Lambda` feature.

I've followed instructions found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python) and [here](http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html).

And I now have the following process to build my `Lambda` function:

### Step 1

Fire a `Amazon Linux EC2` instance and run this as root on it:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Install the SciPy stack on Amazon Linux and prepare it for AWS Lambda

yum -y update
yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum -y install blas --enablerepo=epel
yum -y install lapack --enablerepo=epel
yum -y install atlas-sse3-devel --enablerepo=epel
yum -y install Cython --enablerepo=epel
yum -y install python27
yum -y install python27-numpy.x86_64
yum -y install python27-numpy-f2py.x86_64
yum -y install python27-scipy.x86_64

/usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/stack
/usr/local/bin/pip install moviepy -t /home/ec2-user/stack

cp -R /usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy /home/ec2-user/stack/numpy
cp -R /usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy /home/ec2-user/stack/scipy

tar -czvf stack.tgz /home/ec2-user/stack/*
```

### Step 2

I scp the resulting tarball to my laptop. And then run this script to build a zip archive.

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

mkdir tmp
rm lambda.zip
tar -xzf stack.tgz -C tmp

zip -9 lambda.zip process_movie.py
zip -r9 lambda.zip *.ttf
cd tmp/home/ec2-user/stack/
zip -r9 ../../../../lambda.zip *
```

`process_movie.py` script is at the moment only a test to see if the stack is ok:

```py
def make_movie(event, context):
    import os
    print(os.listdir('.'))
    print(os.listdir('numpy'))
    try:
        import scipy
    except ImportError:
        print('can not import scipy')

    try:
        import numpy
    except ImportError:
        print('can not import numpy')

    try:
        import moviepy
    except ImportError:
        print('can not import moviepy')
```

### Step 3

Then I upload the resulting archive to S3 to be the source of my `lambda` function.
When I test the function I get the following `callstack`:

```
START RequestId: 36c62b93-b94f-11e5-9da7-83f24fc4b7ca Version: $LATEST
['tqdm', 'imageio-1.4.egg-info', 'decorator.pyc', 'process_movie.py', 'decorator-4.0.6.dist-info', 'imageio', 'moviepy', 'tqdm-3.4.0.dist-info', 'scipy', 'numpy', 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf', 'decorator.py', 'moviepy-0.2.2.11.egg-info']
['add_newdocs.pyo', 'numarray', '__init__.py', '__config__.pyc', '_import_tools.py', 'setup.pyo', '_import_tools.pyc', 'doc', 'setupscons.py', '__init__.pyc', 'setup.py', 'version.py', 'add_newdocs.py', 'random', 'dual.pyo', 'version.pyo', 'ctypeslib.pyc', 'version.pyc', 'testing', 'dual.pyc', 'polynomial', '__config__.pyo', 'f2py', 'core', 'linalg', 'distutils', 'matlib.pyo', 'tests', 'matlib.pyc', 'setupscons.pyc', 'setup.pyc', 'ctypeslib.py', 'numpy', '__config__.py', 'matrixlib', 'dual.py', 'lib', 'ma', '_import_tools.pyo', 'ctypeslib.pyo', 'add_newdocs.pyc', 'fft', 'matlib.py', 'setupscons.pyo', '__init__.pyo', 'oldnumeric', 'compat']
can not import scipy
'module' object has no attribute 'core': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/process_movie.py", line 91, in make_movie
    import numpy
  File "/var/task/numpy/__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/var/task/numpy/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/var/task/numpy/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/var/task/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from polynomial import *
  File "/var/task/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as NX
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'

END RequestId: 36c62b93-b94f-11e5-9da7-83f24fc4b7ca
REPORT RequestId: 36c62b93-b94f-11e5-9da7-83f24fc4b7ca  Duration: 112.49 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 1536 MB    Max Memory Used: 14 MB
```

I cant understand why python does not found the core directory that is present in the folder structure.

EDIT:

Following @jarmod advice I've reduced the `lambda`function to:

```py
def make_movie(event, context):
    print('running make movie')
    import numpy
```

I now have the following error:

```
START RequestId: 6abd7ef6-b9de-11e5-8aee-918ac0a06113 Version: $LATEST
running make movie
Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python intepreter from there.: ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/process_movie.py", line 3, in make_movie
    import numpy
  File "/var/task/numpy/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python intepreter from there.

END RequestId: 6abd7ef6-b9de-11e5-8aee-918ac0a06113
REPORT RequestId: 6abd7ef6-b9de-11e5-8aee-918ac0a06113  Duration: 105.95 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 1536 MB    Max Memory Used: 14 MB
```

Comment: Could you try removing any `*.pyc` file before upload.

Comment: @sushant I've added `find tmp -name '*.pyc' -type f -delete` just after the untar but this did not change the result.

Comment: To eliminate issues with your source or filenames, can you re-test with a trivial project that has one simple source file that just imports numpy, does a simple print to stdout and does nothing else?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570011/explain-why-numpy-should-not-be-imported-from-source-directory for advice related to C extensions and where you load numpy from. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good in depth tutorial:
https://serverlesscode.com/post/deploy-scikitlearn-on-lamba/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With the help of all posts in this thread here is a solution for the records:

To get this to work you'll need to:

1. start a `EC2` instance with at least 2GO RAM (to be able to compile `NumPy` & `SciPy`)
2. Install the needed dependencies

   ```
   sudo yum -y update
   sudo yum -y upgrade
   sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
   sudo yum -y install blas --enablerepo=epel
   sudo yum -y install lapack --enablerepo=epel
   sudo yum -y install Cython --enablerepo=epel
   sudo yum install python27-devel python27-pip gcc
   virtualenv ~/env
   source ~/env/bin/activate
   pip install scipy
   pip install numpy
   pip install moviepy
   ```
3. Copy to your locale machine all the content of the directories (except _markerlib, pip*, pkg_resources, setuptools* and easyinstall*) in a `stack` folder:

   - `home/ec2-user/env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
   - `home/ec2-user/env/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages`
4. get all required shared libraries from you `EC2`instance:

   - `libatlas.so.3`
   - `libf77blas.so.3`
   - `liblapack.so.3`
   - `libptf77blas.so.3`
   - `libcblas.so.3`
   - `libgfortran.so.3`
   - `libptcblas.so.3`
   - `libquadmath.so.0`
5. Put them in a `lib` subfolder of the `stack` folder
6. `imageio` is a dependency of `moviepy`, you'll need to download some binary version of its dependencies: `libfreeimage` and of `ffmpeg`; they can be found [here](https://github.com/imageio/imageio-binaries/). Put them at the root of your stack folder and rename `libfreeimage-3.16.0-linux64.so`to `libfreeimage.so`
7. You should now have a `stack` folder containing:

   - all python dependencies at root
   - all shared libraries in a `lib` subfolder
   - `ffmpeg` binary at root
   - `libfreeimage.so` at root
8. Zip this folder: `zip -r9 stack.zip . -x ".*" -x "*/.*"`
9. Use the following `lambda_function.py` as an entry point for your `lambda`

   ```
   from __future__ import print_function

   import os
   import subprocess

   SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
   LIB_DIR = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'lib')
   FFMPEG_BINARY = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'ffmpeg')


   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       command = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH={} IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE={} python movie_maker.py'.format(
           LIB_DIR,
           FFMPEG_BINARY,
       )
       try:
           output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
           print(output)
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
           print(e.output)
   ```
10. write a `movie_maker.py`script that depends on `moviepy`, `numpy`, ...
11. add those to script to your stack.zip file `zip -r9 lambda.zip *.py`
12. upload the zip to `S3` and use it as a source for your `lambda`

You can also download the `stack.zip` [here](http://dvmobile.fr/stackoverflow/lambda-moviepy-stack.zip).

Comment: how did you find the list of shared libraries needed? any command for that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159/show-all-libraries-used-by-executables-on-linux

Comment: @rouk1 How did this work? Total size of contents of site-packages directory is ~250mb which is higher than limit on lambda

Comment: zip command excluds wildcard ".*". In my case this omited `.libs` dir with required shared libraries.

Answer (score 60):

I was also following your first link and managed to import **numpy** and **pandas** in a Lambda function this way (on Windows):

1. Started a (free-tier) **t2.micro** [EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html#ec2-launch-instance_linux) with 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09.1 and used Putty to SSH in.
2. Tried the same **commands** you used and the one recommended by the Amazon article:

   ```
   sudo yum -y update
   sudo yum -y upgrade
   sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
   sudo yum -y install blas --enablerepo=epel
   sudo yum -y install lapack --enablerepo=epel
   sudo yum -y install Cython --enablerepo=epel
   sudo yum install python27-devel python27-pip gcc
   ```
3. Created the **virtual environment**:

   ```
   virtualenv ~/env
   source ~/env/bin/activate
   ```
4. Installed the **packages**:

   ```
   sudo ~/env/bin/pip2.7 install numpy
   sudo ~/env/bin/pip2.7 install pandas
   ```
5. Then, using WinSCP, I logged in and **downloaded** everything (except _markerlib, pip*, pkg_resources, setuptools* and easyinstall*) from `/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, and everything from `/home/ec2-user/env/lib64/python2.7/site-packages` from the EC2 instance.
6. I put all these folders and files into one **zip**, along with the .py file containing the Lambda function.
   [illustration of all files copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tOip.png)
7. Because this .zip is larger than 10 MB, I created an **S3 bucket** to store the file. I copied the link of the file from there and pasted at "Upload a .ZIP from Amazon S3" at the Lambda function.
8. The EC2 instance can be **shut down**, it's not needed any more.

With this, I could import numpy and pandas. I'm not familiar with moviepy, but scipy might already be tricky as Lambda has a **limit** for unzipped deployment package size at 262 144 000 bytes. I'm afraid numpy and scipy together are already over that.

Comment: Installing **matplotlib**: `sudo yum -y install freetype-devel` `sudo yum -y install libpng-devel` `sudo ~/env/bin/pip2.7 --no-cache-dir install matplotlib`

Comment: **matplotlib** also requires downloading `cycler` and `pyparsing` from `/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: Check here for the current Amazon AMI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

Comment: Lambda is all about making sure that we don't have to deal with servers. We're just worrying about the service we trying to avail, right? Then by doing this we are worrying about the server, we're not actually serverless. Also, what will happen if for some reason the host goes down? Will Lambda bring up another node? Will that node have these dependencies installed?

Comment: @Ganesh Satpute - To be clear, the process above is just for **including the required libraries** with your script. You don't have to worry about the administration of your server, but you need to consider what architecture it's going to be, because numpy uses files built for a specific architecture. The EC2 server is only needed here to be able to build these files and then put them into a .zip, it's not needed afterwards. The way Lambda works is that it boots up your .zip content onto a running machine and runs it when needed, and removes it if it's not. You don't need to know which machine.

Answer (score 8):

The posts here help me to find a way to statically compile NumPy with libraries files that can be included in the AWS Lambda Deployment package. This solution does not depend on LD_LIBRARY_PATH value as in @rouk1 solution.

The compiled NumPy library can be downloaded from https://github.com/vitolimandibhrata/aws-lambda-numpy

Here are the steps to custom compile NumPy

#### Instructions on compiling this package from scratch

Prepare a fresh AWS EC instance with AWS Linux.

Install compiler dependencies

```
sudo yum -y install python-devel
sudo yum -y install gcc-c++
sudo yum -y install gcc-gfortran
sudo yum -y install libgfortran
```

Install NumPy dependencies

```
sudo yum -y install blas
sudo yum -y install lapack
sudo yum -y install atlas-sse3-devel
```

Create /var/task/lib to contain the runtime libraries

```
mkdir -p /var/task/lib
```

/var/task is the root directory where your code will reside in AWS Lambda thus we need to statically link the required library files in a well known folder which in this case /var/task/lib

Copy the following library files to the /var/task/lib

```
cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/liblapack.so.3 /var/task/lib/.
cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/libptf77blas.so.3 /var/task/lib/.
cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/libf77blas.so.3 /var/task/lib/.
cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/libptcblas.so.3 /var/task/lib/.
cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/libcblas.so.3 /var/task/lib/.
cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/libatlas.so.3 /var/task/lib/.
cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/libptf77blas.so.3 /var/task/lib/.
cp /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 /var/task/lib/.
cp /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0 /var/task/lib/.
```

Get the latest numpy source code from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/

Go to the numpy source code folder e.g numpy-1.10.4
Create a site.cfg file with the following entries

```
[atlas]
libraries=lapack,f77blas,cblas,atlas
search_static_first=true
runtime_library_dirs = /var/task/lib
extra_link_args = -lgfortran -lquadmath
```

-lgfortran -lquadmath flags are required to statically link gfortran and quadmath libraries with files defined in runtime_library_dirs

Build NumPy

```
python setup.py build
```

Install NumPy

```
python setup.py install
```

Check whether the libraries are linked to the files in /var/task/lib

```
ldd $PYTHON_HOME/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
```

You should see

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe0dd2d000)
liblapack.so.3 => /var/task/lib/liblapack.so.3 (0x00007ffad6be5000)
libptf77blas.so.3 => /var/task/lib/libptf77blas.so.3 (0x00007ffad69c7000)
libptcblas.so.3 => /var/task/lib/libptcblas.so.3 (0x00007ffad67a7000)
libatlas.so.3 => /var/task/lib/libatlas.so.3 (0x00007ffad6174000)
libf77blas.so.3 => /var/task/lib/libf77blas.so.3 (0x00007ffad5f56000)
libcblas.so.3 => /var/task/lib/libcblas.so.3 (0x00007ffad5d36000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ffad596d000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /var/task/lib/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007ffad5654000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffad5352000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /var/task/lib/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007ffad5117000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffad4f00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffad4b3e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffad4922000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffad471d000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ffad451a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055cfc3ab8000)
```

Comment: I have tried this. However, I am seeing liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 instead of liblapack.so.3 => /var/task/lib/liblapack.so.3.

Comment: I have used the same site.cfg file

Comment: @Zzz. I have encountered this issue before. You need to delete the existing NumPy installation folder and to restart the compilation process. Hope that it works!

Comment: I have tried a number of times. I have not installed it but I checked the build. It is not using the runtime libraries directory at all. Could you please include libblas.so.3 also in your build. Thanks. @Vito Limandibhrata

Comment: In my case, *.a files are also required to build numpy for runtime_library_dirs , otherwise site-cfg is going to be ignored. Just need to do cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/*.a /var/task/lib/. (numpy==1.11.1)

Also, if you think site-cfg is ignored, just run python setup.py config to know what's the problem, then you can see what's going on.

Tip, if you use pip, just create ~/.numpy-site.cfg and put [atlas] part into there then use pip.

Comment: I tried to use the compiled library but I had the error "dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)"

Answer (score 6):

Another, very simple method that's possible these days is to build using the awesome docker containers that LambCI made to mimic Lambda: https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda

The `lambci/lambda:build` container resembles AWS Lambda with the addition of a mostly-complete build environment. To start a shell session in it:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task -it lambci/lambda:build bash
```

Inside the session:

```
export share=/var/task
easy_install pip
pip install -t $share numpy
```

Or, with virtualenv:

```
export share=/var/task
export PS1="[\u@\h:\w]\$ " # required by virtualenv
easy_install pip
pip install virtualenv
# ... make the venv, install numpy, and copy it to $share
```

Later on you can use the main lambci/lambda container to test your build.

Comment: what do you do after having installed numpy inside docker? i.e. how to get it to work on lambda? would it be possible to run these executables from another runtime, like node.js, too?

Answer (score 6):

As of 2017, NumPy and SciPy have wheels that work on Lambda (the packages include precompiled `libgfortran` and `libopenblas`).
As far as I know, MoviePy is a pure Python module, so basically you could do:

```sh
pip2 install -t lambda moviepy scipy
```

Then copy your handler into the `lambda` directory and zip it. Except, that you'll most likely exceed the 50/250 MB size limits. There are a couple of things that can help:

- remove .pycs, docs, tests and other unnecessary parts;
- leave a single copy of common libraries of NumPy and SciPy;
- strip libraries of inessential pieces, such as debugging symbols;
- compress the archive using higher settings.

Here's an example [script](https://gist.github.com/wrwrwr/4a38a17113e3845f3385e9388effc064) that automates the above points.

Comment: What does 'NumPy and SciPy have wheels' mean? I see that there is a numpy-1.14.0.dist-info directory that contains a WHEEL file. I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) and I'm still getting the `Unable to import module 'solution': Missing required dependencies ['numpy']` error.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018, Steps to install external modules in Python3 on AWS EC2:

1. Launch EC2 on Amazon Linux AMI 201709.
2. ssh with putty using private and public key and become super user.
3. Install Python 3 and create virtual env, then make it default

   ```
   yum install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip

   virtualenv -p python3.6 /tmp/my_python_lib

   source /tmp/my_python_lib/bin/activate

   which python --to check which version s installed

   pip3 install  numpy
   ```
4. Copy files under site packages and dist packages into your local machhine using winscp.

   To find actual location use grep commands ---

   ```
     grep -r dist-packages *.
   ```

These packages could be inside both lib and lib64.

5. Site and dist packages will be under location:

   ```
   /tmp/my_python_lib/lib64/python3.6,
   /tmp/my_python_lib/lib/python3.6
   ```
6. Zip these packages along with your script file and upload to S3 which can be accessed in lambda.Instead of zipping the root folder you have to select all files and zip it or send to compressed folder.

Additional tips:

1. If you want to install all packages under one directory, you can use command:

   ```
    pip install --upgrade --target=/tmp/my_python_lib/lib/python3.6/dist-packages pandas
   ```

Answer (score 3):

As of August 2018, probably the easiest way is to start a [new AWS Cloud9 environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/create-environment.html).
Then create a Lambda function inside the environment. Next run this into the Cloud9 command line:

```
    cd YourApplicationName
    /venv/bin/pip install scipy -t .
    /venv/bin/pip install numpy -t .
    /venv/bin/pip install moviepy -t .
```

Now I am able to import the modules in the lambda_handler function.

Comment: Requires setting up ec2... we want to avoid that and only use Lambda

Comment: @JohnAndrews I don't think you need to setup an ec2. Or do you mean the ec2 that Cloud9 is running on?

Comment: Not sure, I gave up and switched to Google Cloud Functions. Can't explain how much easier it is (set it up literally in 30 minutes what you tried to do above) and the docs are much much much much much better.

Comment: @karoli does that mean u have venv folder in your lambda? I thought we usually don't check in venv folder.

Comment: @Jun711 Yes, the venv folder is in the lambda. Not sure what you mean by "check in venv folder".

Comment: @karoli I see. I meant git commit by 'check in venv folder'. I normally have git ignore venv. Another question, have you tried using libraries that depend on scipy / numpy in lambda?

Comment: @Jun711 Pandas seems to work fine, and it has a dependency on numpy.

Answer (score 2):

**Nov 2018**. Hi friends, this post is extremely helpful for me. However, the answers so far are not very automated. I wrote a Python script and tutorial here https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/6a6a25d594cc07146c60af943f74c16f to automate the creation of compiled Python packages using `pip` and `virtualenv` on EC2. Everything is Python (Boto3), no bash script, no Web console, no `awscli`.

There are one other change besides automation, which I think is an improvement. I downloaded the whole Python virtual environment from EC2 preserving its folder structures, instead of merging `lib` and `lib64` packages all together. I never understand the intended meaning of merging those two folders. What if some packages override other packages, right? Plus, faking an official virtual environment is non-the-less a safer way to go than rolling your own.

For the downloaded virtual environment to work, the source code of the Lambda function adds some boilerplate code to update Python search path using `sys.path`. The intended `sys.path` of a Python virtual environment can be found by

- On your own machine, create a virtual environment and activate it.
- Run a Python script in this virtual environment and do `print(sys.path)` after `import sys`.
  You can start from there and modify as you see fit.

A snippet of the boilerplate code to add for a Lambda function in order to load `numpy` and other packages from my packaged virtual environment is pasted below. In my case, I loaded `pandas_datareader` which relies on `numpy`.

```
import os
import sys 

# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html
workdir = os.getenv('LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT')
version = f'{sys.version_info[0]}.{sys.version_info[1]}'
additionals = [f'{workdir}/venv/lib64/python{version}/site-packages',
               f'{workdir}/venv/lib64/python{version}/lib-dynload',
               f'{workdir}/venv/lib64/python{version}/dist-packages',
               f'{workdir}/venv/lib/python{version}/dist-packages',
               f'{workdir}/venv/lib/python{version}/site-packages']
sys.path = additionals + sys.path

import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the steps posted by @attila-tanyi work correctly under Amazon Linux. I would only add that there is no need to use an EC2, as there is an Amazon Linux docker container available from the default repository.

```
docker pull amazonlinux && docker run -it amazonlinux
# Follow @attila-tanyi steps
# Note - sudo is not necessary here
```

I use the Dockerfile embedded in my application to build and deploy to Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Vito Limandibhrata's answer but I think it's not enough to build numpy with runtime_library_dirs in numpy==1.11.1. If anybody think site-cfg is ignored, do the following:

```
cp /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3/*.a /var/task/lib/
```

*.a files under atlas-sse3 are needed to build numpy. Also, you might need to run the following:

```
python setup.py config
```

to check numpy configuration. If it requires something more, you will see the following message:

```
atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /root/Envs/skl/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /root/Envs/skl/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64   
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib         
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack not found in ['/var/task/lib']
Runtime library lapack was not found. Ignoring
    libraries f77blas not found in ['/var/task/lib']
Runtime library f77blas was not found. Ignoring
    libraries cblas not found in ['/var/task/lib']
Runtime library cblas was not found. Ignoring
    libraries atlas not found in ['/var/task/lib']
Runtime library atlas was not found. Ignoring
    FOUND:
        extra_link_args = ['-lgfortran -lquadmath']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', -1)]
        language = f77
        libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas', 'lapack', 'f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas-sse3']
        include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
```

then site-cfg is going to be ignored.

Tip: If pip is used to build numpy with runtime_library_dirs, you would better create `~/.numpy-site.cfg` and add the following:

```
[atlas]
libraries = lapack,f77blas,cblas,atlas
search_static_first = true
runtime_library_dirs = /var/task/lib
extra_link_args = -lgfortran -lquadmath
```

then numpy recognizes .numpy-site.cfg file. It's quite simple and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create zip file for lambda with scipy, numpy, moviepy and pandas on any OS.

https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#files

pypi has wheel files for different OS and you can download manylinux whl file and unzip. After that remove dist-info and pyc files and zip all.
The final zip file can be uploaded to S3 then and converted into lambda layer.

[This](https://korniichuk.medium.com/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e) tutorial is helpful to understand it deeply.