# Installing numpy on AWS Lambda server - C dependency error, no gcc

Tags: python, numpy, gcc, pip, aws-lambda

I've been successfully able to install python modules in my python lambda function using `subprocess`, a virtual environment, and `pip` calls. However, this only works if they don't have C dependencies, like with `numpy` or `pandas` (the `subprocess.check_output()` call only says it fails with exit status 1).

It appears that the lambda servers don't have `gcc` installed, and there's no `apt-get` to install or `sudo`, `chroot` or similar command to let give permission. It does have `install` so I may be able to install it locally if I can find a standalone `gcc` package, but since I don't have root access or `chroot` I suspect that won't work.

At this point I don't care about the right way to do this since it seems like Amazon doesn't want me to be doing this, any workaround to get C-dependent python modules to install would be fantastic.

Comment: `ubuntu` has `numpy` binaries in its repositories, so it can be installed without compiling.  But the same lack of permissions may keep you from loading those.

Comment: Lambda does not run Ubuntu. Not sure how you got that idea. Lambda runs Amazon Linux, as is clearly documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34882192/3160869) on how to install **numpy** and **pandas** in Amazon Lambda.