# Aws Lambda: Deploy a python function with numpy dependency

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda

Installed `numpy` on my project folder using `pip install numpy -t <project dir>` command. I can see `numpy` and `numpy-1.12.1.dist-info` in the project directory. 
But when I zip the directory and run it on Lambda I get
 `Unable to import module 'handler': Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`

> Unable to import module 'handler':  Importing the multiarray numpy
>   extension module failed.  Most likely you are trying to import a
>   failed build of numpy. If you're working with a numpy git repo, try
>   `git clean -xdf` (removes all files not under version control). 
>   Otherwise reinstall numpy.

What is wrong with my project?

Answer (score 0):

Check where your numpy is getting installed e.g $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages

After that follow these steps-

```
  cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  zip -r9 <path_to_your_lambda_function_zip>/awslambda.zip *
```

This will add all libs in the site-packages into the zip which you can upload directly

Comment: Copied all python packages to project folder `cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages zip -r9 ~/Documents/my-service/awslambda.zip *` then zipped the project folder with python function and tested with lambda. Still getting the same error.

Comment: in the zip file check what are the libs installed ? and see if numpy is installed or not?  are you using virtualenv ?

Comment: Yes I tried using the virtualenv. If you check the error message, numpy is being recognized but there is some issue with how it is compiled.

Comment: I think you might be missing some numpy dependencies in that zip . I tried with zip -r9 <path_to_your_lambda_function_zip>/awslambda.zip *  i.e. recursively copy all libs into zip and upload it to lambda and it is working for me . check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda