# AWS Lambda function in python not running and saying scikit-learn has not been built correctly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, virtualenv

I have the following, very simple python code in a lambda function:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import praw
import datetime
from operator import attrgetter
import sys

def handler_name(event, context):
    return "I am a cat dog and i meow."
```

I have also done pip installs for scikit-learn, praw, datetime, numpy and scipy from within a python 2.7 virtualenv. I then compressed my .py file along with everything in my virtualenv's /lib/python2.7/site-packages folder into a zip and uploaded it to AWS lambda. Unfortunately when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Unable to import module 'mainLambda': /var/task/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.so: invalid ELF header
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /var/task/sklearn/__check_build:
setup.py                  _check_build.so           __init__.pyc
__init__.py               setup.pyc
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

Obviously the issue is with sk-learn. I have no idea what though. It could be a versioning issue but I downloaded all the libraries from within a virtulenv and chose a python2.7 lambda function. Any idea? I am stumped!

Comment: Did you download a 64 bit version of the library?

Comment: I am not sure - how can i check/am I meant to download the 64bit?

Comment: Did you compile scikit-learn on amazonlinux? Might be the same issue as with every other complex library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda/34972163

Comment: i did not compile scikit-learn on amazon linux - not sure what that means but i will look into it.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?