# Numpy imported, but no functions found in AWS lambda function

Tags: python, numpy, aws-lambda

I'm working on a lambda function that partly depends on numpy. I created a deployment package zip with a test script that imports numpy and then tries to subtract two numbers using np.subtract since it was having trouble finding the numpy functions.

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.subtract(4,2)
print(a)
```

I'm working with a python3.5 virtualenv on a linux EC2 instance. To create the deployment zip, I installed numpy, placed my script into site-packages and zipped the contents of the folder as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html). I can create the lambda function from the zip file with no problem, but when I trigger it, it gives the error:

`module initialization error: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'subtract'`

It appears to import numpy, but it can't find any of the functions. I assume I packaged the libraries/script wrong, but I thought I was following the directions correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference the module when you import it. A bit of code always helps.

```
import numpy

a=2
b=1
c=numpy.subtract(a,b)
print c
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better if I didn't reference it as np, but did it directly like you did? 
Edited the main question to include the test code.

Comment: The package might need to be unzipped for access to numpy? Does it work local, just not on EC2?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda?rq=1), and I was able to adapt the solution for my needs. It was how I packaged the libraries.