# AWS Lambda/Python3 can't import numpy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda

I have a python3.6 script that uses sqlalchemy, pandas and numpy.  To get this working on AWS Lambda, I took the following steps.

1. Created a new, clean directory
2. Create a new virtualenv
3. Create a holding directory (`mkdir dist`)
4. Install packages `pip install sqlalchemy numpy pandas`
5. Navigate to packages `cd env/lib/python3.6/site-packages`
6. Zip packages to holding directory `zip -r path/dist/Transfer.zip .`
7. Navigate to root
8. Zip python file `zip -g dist/Transfer.zip my_python.py`
9. Upload to S3
10. Direct Lambda > Configuration > Code entry type > Upload a file from S3 > path to my file
11. Set Handler to my_python.lambda_handler
12. Save and test

I always get the error

> {
>     "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'my_python'"
>   }

With the logs as

> Unable to import module 'heap_consolidation_lambda': Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Why can it not see numpy?  Fwiw, numpy is the third import, so apparently it has no issues with sqlalchemy and pandas.

Comment: Did you look at the discussion here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda

Comment: My guess is that numpy is not pure python, therefore some extra compilation is needed.

Comment: yeah, these need to be compiled on amazon linux ec2.