# AWS Lambda Logs using AWSCLI: How can I access Lambda logs using AWSCLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I was trying to work with AWS Lambda using the awscli on an ubuntu ec2 instance, and I do not have access to the aws console. Note that I am not using serverless or zapper, I directly zip my main.py file along with the dependency files as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34882192/8872639)

I run the function like this

`aws lambda invoke --function-name python-test --invocation-type RequestResponse outfile.txt`

The errors given in the outfile are very vague and dont help in debugging, rather they confuse me more. Using the admin's system, I am able to recognize the errors when I run a test on the console, but How can I check those logs using the awscli ?

So I tried running `aws cloudwatch list-metrics > cloudwatch_logs.log`
and searching the function name 'python-test' in the cloudwatch_logs.log file, I am able to find `Namespace`, `MetricName`, `Dimensions` for this function, but how do you access the logs ?

Any help with links to similar examples greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 71, accepted):

First, get the **log group** name:

```
aws logs describe-log-groups --query logGroups[*].logGroupName
[
    "/aws/lambda/MyFunction"
]
```

Then, list the **log streams** for that log group:

```
aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/MyFunction' --query logStreams[*].logStreamName

[
    "2018/02/07/[$LATEST]140c61ffd59442b7b8405dc91d708fdc"
]
```

Finally, get the **log events** for that stream:

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/MyFunction' --log-stream-name '2018/02/07/[$LATEST]140c61ffd59442b7b8405dc91d708fdc'

{
    "nextForwardToken": "f/33851760153448034063427449515194237355552440866456338433", 
    "events": [
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1517965421523, 
            "timestamp": 1517965421526, 
            "message": "START RequestId: bca9c478-0ba2-11e8-81db-4bccfc644168 Version: $LATEST\n"
        }, 
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1517965424581, 
            "timestamp": 1517965424567, 
            "message": "END RequestId: bca9c478-0ba2-11e8-81db-4bccfc644168\n"
        }, 
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1517965424581, 
            "timestamp": 1517965424567, 
            "message": "REPORT RequestId: bca9c478-0ba2-11e8-81db-4bccfc644168\tDuration: 3055.39 ms\tBilled Duration: 3100 ms \tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 35 MB\t\n"
        }
    ], 
    "nextBackwardToken": "b/33851760085631457914695824538087252860391482425578356736"
}
```

Comment: Arigato Gozaimasu !
This will save me a lot of time !

Comment: If you get `An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the DescribeLogStreams operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded` when querying anything. Just add `--limit 10` option to your command. Eg.  `aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name "/aws/lambda/my-lambda-function" --query logStreams[*].logStreamName --limit 20`

Comment: `aws logs describe-log-groups --query logGroups[*].logGroupName` shows `[]`
 for me... hmm

Comment: If you know the name of the log-group-name you can use `filter-log-events` to get all log streams in one go - optionally filtered by `--start-time` https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html

Answer (score 9):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) flavor:

List AWS lambda group name (if list is too big you might want to filter it with [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/)):

```
aws logs describe-log-groups | jq -r ".logGroups[].logGroupName"
```

Then read `message` property from latest stream with:

```
LOG_GROUP_NAME="/aws/lambda/awesomeFunction"
LOG_STREAM_NAME=$(aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name "${LOG_GROUP_NAME}" | jq -r '.logStreams | sort_by(.creationTime) | .[-1].logStreamName')
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name "${LOG_GROUP_NAME}" --log-stream-name "${LOG_STREAM_NAME}" | jq -r '.events[] | select(has("message")) | .message'
```

You might want to put this in a `logs.sh` file.

If you want more or other streams you might want to tweak the `.logStreams[0]` part

Answer (score 2):

Using the AWS CLI can be a bit irritating because the stream name changes as you modify your function. I've found that using awslogs (https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs) is a nicer workflow.

List the groups:

```
awslogs groups
```

Filter results.

```
awslogs groups|grep myfunction
```

Then get the logs from the group.

```
awslogs get /aws/lambda/ShortenStack-mutationShortenLambdaBC1758AD-6KW0KAD3TYVE
```

It defaults to the last 5 minutes, but you can add the -s parameter to choose a time, e.g `-s 10m` for the last 10 minutes.

The output is colourised if you're at the terminal, or plain if you're piping it through other commands, e.g. grep to find something.

Answer (score 2):

This one liner invokes the lambda function and prints the logs in your terminal:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name my-lambda-function --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{"foo":"bar"}' output.json --log-type Tail --query 'LogResult' --output text | base64 -d
```