# Check CW log-group of a lambda through CLI

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have only programmatic access to AWS cloud watch and other services. I created a lambda and event source mapping with DynamoDB. It uploaded and ran successfully but I don't know which log group is it logging. Is there a way through the CLI to check which log group a lambda is configured with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda Logs using AWSCLI: How can I access Lambda logs using AWSCLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794781/aws-lambda-logs-using-awscli-how-can-i-access-lambda-logs-using-awscli)

Comment: Thanks. It partially does. There are 10 different log groups. How do I know in which log group my logs are going?

Comment: The log group is named `/aws/lambda/<function name>`.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html

Comment: I created a new function and I don't see a log group for this new function. I do see for all other functions.

Comment: The log group will only be created after you make at least one invocation of that function.

Comment: I did invoke a few.

Comment: Could you post the policies attached to the execution role of this particular lambda function? I suspect it may not have permission to push logs to cloudwatch.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I check through CLI?