# Error while creating custom resource trigger for lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I created a lambda via ts file with the following specifications:

```
        description: 'Lambda request handler to automate the DDL commands',
        name: LAMBDA_NAME,
        timeout: Duration.minutes(10),
        memorySize: 512,
        componentName: 'DdlLambda',
        runtime: Runtime.JAVA_11,
        handler: 'handler.ddllambda',
        packageName: 'DDLManagementLambda-1.0',
        deadLetterQueueEnabled: false,
        tracing: Tracing.ACTIVE,
        profiling: false,
        logRetention: RetentionDays.FOUR_MONTHS
```

Created a custom resource with

```
import {CustomResource} from "monocdk";

const customResource = new CustomResource(this, 'CustomResource', {
  serviceToken: ddllambda.functionArn,
  properties: {
      version: "version_0"
  }
```

But I am getting the error

```
CloudFormation did not receive a response from your Custom Resource. 
Please check your logs for requestId [c634da01-9c4d-4f8e-a2fc-a28724aa8206]. 
If you are using the Python cfn-response module, you may need to update your 
Lambda function code so that CloudFormation can attach the updated version.
```

I am not able to find the logs for the given requestId. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you provide your lambda's code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sending the response back from lambda, hence was getting the error. Referring this code helped https://github.com/stelligent/cloudformation-custom-resources/blob/master/lambda/java/src/main/java/com/stelligent/customresource/CustomResourceHandler.java.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`cfn-response.send`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html) in your custom resource to notify **CloudFormation**.

---

### Find logs in the console:

For the logs, you can access them from the console in the lambda page, click **Monitor** then **View logs in CloudWatch**:

[image: Lambda console access CloudWatch]

Once in **CloudWatch** click **Search all**:

[image: CloudWatch LogStream search all]

Then in the search box paste your **Request ID** in **double quotes**:

[image: Search Logs by Request ID]

---

### Find logs using `aws-cli`: See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795122/9434800)