# Using aws encryption SDK in python AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I tried using the aws encryption lib to encrypt/decrypt data with a KMS key in an AWS Lambda ( using python ). However, I get errors when running the lambda ( complaining about shared libs not found, I will update later with exact lib ). I am guessing that the SDK is using shared libs that are not installed in the AWS lambda environment.

This is the SDK I am using: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/python.html

When building my package I am doing pip install aws-encryption-sdk and cryptography.

Anyone who can give me pointers how to fix it?

Update:

Here is the error message:

`Unable to import module 'lambdaMain': libffi-d78936b1.so.6.0.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Update 2:
For those wondering about the solution. I built the library on the wrong platform. It's really important to do the pip install etc on an amazon AMI that's compatible with whatever lambda runtime you are using.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the exact error message? Are you building the Lambda package manually? Are you using Serverless/SAM/Zappa/etc?

Comment: I updated the question with the error message. I am building the lambda package manually on a build server. Not using serverless/sam/zappa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aws-encryption-sdk` [requires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/python.html) cryptography library:

> The SDK requires the cryptography library on all platforms. All
>   versions of pip install and build the cryptography library on Windows.
>   pip 8.1 and later installs and builds cryptography on Linux. If you
>   are using an earlier version of pip and your Linux environment doesn't
>   have the tools needed to build the cryptography library, you need to
>   install them. For more information, see Building cryptography on
>   Linux.

It seems the Lambda environment does not have the required libraries, so you need to add them.

Unfortunately Miserlou's [lambda-packages](https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages) does not have it, so you need to compile yourself.

Couple pointers:

- [Using moviepy, scipy and numpy in amazon lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34882192/2190251)
- [Running Python with compiled code on AWS Lambda](http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html)
- [Using Native Dependencies with AWS Lambda](https://instil.co/2017/08/07/using-native-dependencies-with-aws-lambda/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 3):

I had multiple issues when trying to package my libs / requirements and heres the steps that resolved the issue for me:

1) Create a new EC2 instance using Amazon Linux AMI

2) Install any requirements
`sudo yum install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip  -y`

3) Create new virtual enviroment using python3 `virtualenv -p python3 .`

4) Install any requirements using pip3
`pip3 install aws_encryption_sdk`

5) Everything in both lib and lib64 must be added (including hidden files)

```
zip -r -9 /tmp/export.zip lib64/python3.6/site-packages/* lib64/python3.6/site-packages/.*
zip -r -9 /tmp/export.zip lib/python3.6/site-packages/* lib/python3.6/site-packages/.*
zip -r -9 /tmp/export.zip main.py
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also needed to add system libraries. so I copied the contents of `/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/` into `lib64/python3.6/site-packages/` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` into `lib/python3.6/site-packages/` make sure to use `cp -r /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/.*` so it copies hidden files.

Comment: I just got the libffi-806b1a9d.so.6.0.4 file and distributed it w/ my code. Python 3.6. I have it a try and it worked. On my code I just ship it w/ cryptografy.