# AWS Lambda Bootstrap errors

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run a microservice on AWS Lambda and because it requires NumPy and pymysql dependencies I've followed the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda)

I receive this error upon uploading the dependencies and code to S3 and trying to run my test functions.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 538, in <module>
    main()
  File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 528, in main
    run_init_handler(init_handler, invokeid)
  File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 94, in run_init_handler
    init_handler()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any ideas on what could have happened? It runs fine on both my EC2 instance and my local computer

Comment: How do you deploy your function? Maybe you passed your module name instead of the handler function?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda now has "layers" which could / should help you with that now.

But for others in the future, I had the exact same problem.

I had just finished refactoring a single-file Lambda Python module to a set of files, which included `init.py`. Turns out that if you have a module named `init.py` sitting next to a `__init__.py` in a package, some part of the AWS bootstrap processes can't handle the import or errors relating to the import; whether the file is good during import (your function times out) or bad (the traceback above).

I renamed `init.py` to `connect.py` (because I'm only setting up connection information for on-demand connections), then stopped seeing OP's traceback, and was able to move on.

I haven't attempted to reproduce with variations on `init*.py` module names.

Very strange edge case to run into.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this in a serverless app and it turns out it was down to how the handler was defined in the `serverless.yaml`. The bootstrap will take this value and try to execute it. In my case it was not pointing to a function in my python file but was pointing to one of the modules within the file.

```yaml
functions:
  some_lambda:
    handler: src/somefile.jwt
```

In somefile.py there was an import for jwt. Code was meant to call a func `jwt_auth` but ended up trying to call the jwt module, causing the error seen by the OP.