# AWS Lambda function requires numpy - but yields "Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed." error

Tags: numpy, aws-lambda, importerror

On Mac I installed numpy via:
sudo pip install -t /mydirectoryhere/ numpy

with:
Password:
The directory '/Users/elliotbricker/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/mydirectoryhere/' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/c1/d5c47de35e366b1c2f60da88a24b25d3037b892417c5c3c5398313fb54f5/numpy-1.15.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (24.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 24.5MB 762kB/s 
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.1

Then when I archived the package for Lambda and ran the TEST on AWS for this Lambda function, I get:

{
  "errorMessage": "\nImporting the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most\nlikely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.\nIf you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all\nfiles not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.\n\nOriginal error was: /var/task/numpy/core/multiarray.so: invalid ELF header\n",
  "errorType": "ImportError",
  "stackTrace": [

The above pip install produced three directories:
bin
numpy
numpy-1.15.1.dist-info

My compressed archive contains all three of the above directories

Comment: Similar problems are walked through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda)

Comment: I ran into the same issue with Lambda. Haven't been able to figure it out yet.