# How to import numpy in Pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, module, pycharm

After installing `numpy` in PyCharm, how do you import it?.

After importing it and defining a function I got the error:

[[image]

Comment: am a newbie to using pycharm.kindly help in the procedure of restarting

Comment: I guess you need to install the library instead of running it, `pip install numpy`, the addresses in your error traceback...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain why numpy should not be imported from source directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570011/explain-why-numpy-should-not-be-imported-from-source-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should import numpy in the codes and usually rename it as np. 
add code below like this.

```
import numpy as np
```

Answer (score 0):

It took long to get to this solution
first , create a virtual environment
and then install package manager pip or pip3
there after you can comfortably :
`import numpy as np`