# Installing pandas in a venv on raspberry pi

Tags: python, pandas, linux, numpy, raspberry-pi

I am using Python 3.9.2 on my Raspberry Pi 3b+, and running my code in a virtual environment named **venv** with the following installed:

```
Package            Version
------------------ ------------
blinker            1.7.0
click              8.1.7
flask              3.0.0
importlib-metadata 7.0.0
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
MarkupSafe         2.1.3
numpy              1.26.2
pandas             2.1.3
pip                20.3.4
pkg-resources      0.0.0
python-dateutil    2.8.2
pytz               2023.3.post1
setuptools         44.1.1
six                1.16.0
tzdata             2023.3
werkzeug           3.0.1
zipp               3.17.0
```

When I try to import numpy or pandas like so:

```
import numpy
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/Repositories/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

I just don't understans how I can be in the numpy source tree, when running from root in a dir like this:

- venv/
- app.py

I have tried the solutions mentioned in the post, unfortunately with no luck: [Explain why numpy should not be imported from source directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570011/explain-why-numpy-should-not-be-imported-from-source-directory)

Anyone who have tried something similar?

Comment: Why do you think this would this be different on a Raspberry Pi than anywhere else? Have you tested that the same steps _don't_ reproduce it on other hardware? If not, why is that part of the title?

Comment: See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.3/pandas/__init__.py#L26-L32 -- pandas adds that warning to _any_ ImportError that might happen while trying to set up numpy. It's just a guess about a common mistake people make, not an authoritative diagnostic.

Comment: ...and once you've looked up the line in pandas that throws the error, that tells you that you can run `from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev`; if _that_ import fails it can cause the message to be thrown as a false alarm. For us to give you a better answer, we need to know _how_ it fails.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, appreciate the help!

The reason I think it would be different on a Raspberry Pi is that the same code with the same dependencies and versions runs fine on my Windows 11 laptop, thus, I cannot reproduce the error on my laptop.

I tried running: "from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev", and unfortunately it gave the same error.

Comment: _nod_ -- you've got a lot of differences between a Windows 11 system and a Raspberry Pi that go beyond the hardware itself; a like-for-like "is this really a raspi-only problem?" reproducer would be a different arm64-based Linux system (assuming it's 64-bit, or arm32 otherwise, depending on whether you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit raspian). Can also emulate such a system with qemu.

Comment: Anyhow, can you successfully _just_ run `import numpy`, without involving pandas at all? Even if you get the same error, you should get a different stack trace telling us what line inside the numpy source tree to look in; please [edit] that into the question.

Comment: Right, I just tried "import numpy" and it gave same error...

Comment: How did you create the virtual env and install your dependencies? You do you launch you code?

Comment: I created the venv with the default version of Python that came with Raspberry OS with: "python -m venv venv", and I installed dependencies with "pip install pandas flask". I launch the code with bash "python main.py", after I activate the venv

Comment: I did the same steps `python -m venv venv`, `source venv/bin/activate`, `pip install pandas` (as pandas and numpy are the matter, I skip flask). Then in a python console, I tried to import numpy. I get an error but not the same than yours but I get a message about a missing `libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file`. After installing openblas with `sudo apt install libopenblas-dev/stable`, it works.