# pandas ImportError in pycharm, Error importing numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-packaging

I think my python library pacakges are messed up.
if I import pandas on my pycharm IDE it gets following import error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ribahshaikh/Desktop/hht_app/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/ribahshaikh/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

The same code works fine if I run it from the terminal.
The project is using system interpreter i.e. /usr/bin/python3.9 in pycharm

Comment: Perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570011/explain-why-numpy-should-not-be-imported-from-source-directory